# What is projection from a plane to other plane of a point in Fourier Domain?

Tags: geometry, fourier-analysis, projective-geometry

I know that translation movement of point A(X,Y) in space is invariant in Fourier domain, while the rotation movement of point gives rotation movement in Fourier domain.

What is the expression and its proof (reference, book, etc) of the projection from a plane to other plane of a point in Fourier Domain, using projective matrix?

Comment: Have you found the answer? Can you share it? Thanks

Comment: unfortunately I did not find the answer.